# html5+canvas+getusermedia: how to rec video

Tags: html, canvas, html5-video, webcam

I want to record video from `getUserMedia`.
Its[demo page](http://gifbox.ru/webcam/)or [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/LNbeH/1/) (Press Start, then Stop, then Play recorded)
Every 67ms I make snapshot of the canvas and add data64 to array by: `video_arr.push(canvas.toDataURL());`

Frame rate of my "recorded" video (when to press Play recorded) is smaller than one frame in 67 ms. Why?

Or can somebody tell true way of record and then playing video from getUserMedia?

Answer (score 0):

Its just an idea to do it. I hope it should help you.

Use blobbuilder to store the recorded frames and you need to convert the canvas data to blob for that use polyfill canvas to blob

here is the polyfill usage and download

http://eligrey.com/blog/

https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob

```
var bb = new BlobBuilder();//global variable


//record for every frame
canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
   bb.append(blob)
});


//onstop upload the blob builder data to server
```